# Upgrading to ember-data 1.0.0.beta.11 causes "Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Any idea why? I have a big app and haven't yet been able to find where this is coming from.

This error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable
```

does not happen when using previous versions of ember-data.